# Asymptotic Independence of random walks from increments?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, random-walks

Suppose we have two random walks $(S_n:n\geq 1)$ and $(T_n:n\geq 1)$ building from independent identically distributed increment vectors $\{(X_k,Y_k):k\geq 1\}$, i.e. $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k, T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$, for different $k$'s vectors $(X_k,Y_k)$ are jointly independent with identical marginal distributions, but within each vector $X_k$ is correlated with $Y_k$ and the correlation depends on $k$.

However, suppose the correlation is decreasing, indicating an asymptotic independence between $X_k$ and $Y_k$. Actually, say we have quantitative control $$\mathbb{E}[e^{i\alpha X_k+i\beta Y_k}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{i\alpha X_k}]\mathbb{E}[e^{i\beta Y_k}]e^{O(F_k(\alpha,\beta))}$$
with $F_k(\alpha,\beta)\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$ in any desired way (eg. uniform or having certain decreasing rate or...).

My question is: given these controls, can we get a quantitative control over the asymptotic independence of the path properties of the two random walks? Eg., can we say there is some $N$ large enough, so that for any event $$\mathcal{E}=\{\forall N\leq n\leq 2N: S_n-S_N\in A_n,T_n-T_N\in B_n\}$$ defined with any choices of intervals $A_n,B_n$, we have $$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})=(1+o(1))\mathbb{P}(\forall N\leq n\leq 2N: S_n-S_N\in A_n)\mathbb{P}(\forall N\leq n\leq 2N: T_n-T_N\in B_n)?$$